# 14.04 update broke my rutorrent setup

Tags: nginx, javascript, rutorrent

I just updated my system and now my rutorrent isn't working. When I go to the web page, I get this error

```
JS error: [http://192.168.0.36/rutorrent/js/jquery.js : 2] TypeError: a is null
```

I searched for that, and all I found is that it fixed itself after a reboot for someone else. Tried that, not for me.

I am using nginx as a web server for rutorrent.

I installed it using [these instructions](http://vassie.me/rtorrent-and-rutorrent-on-ubuntu-server-with-nginx/).

Any ideas?

Comment: Did you find any answer to this? Having the same issue

Comment: Twice in a row Ubuntu updates have broken my rutorrent setup.  After getting ZERO help from the IRC channel, I changed the web server to Apache.  It solved the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Open your site's nginx configuration `/etc/nginx/sites-available/yoursite`

'yoursite' is the name of whatever you named your site.  Mine was 'default'.

Change `include fastcgi_params;` to `include fastcgi.conf;` and restart the service:

```
sudo service nginx restart
```